# How to listen to events that got fired in shadow dom of child element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I have two web-components, one is something like a list-item and the other one is the container. In the list item there is a button, which dispatches an event onclick. Both components use separated shadow-doms.

```
<custom-list>
        <custom-list-item></custom-list-item>
        <custom-list-item></custom-list-item>
        <custom-list-item></custom-list-item>
</custom-list>
```

How can I listen in 'custom-list' to the event that gets emitted by the button in 'custom-list-item'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the container custom element `<custom-list>`, simply listen to the `click` element on the Shadow DOM root. The `click` event emitted by the  element in the inner Shadow DOM will naturally bubble to its container.

```
this.shadowRoot.addEventListener( 'click', ev => console.log( ev.target.id ) )
```

You can also implement the `handleEvent()` method to process all the events managed inside your custom element:

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-list-item', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `<button>Click</button>`             
    }  
} )

customElements.define( 'custom-list', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super() 
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `
                <custom-list-item id=1></custom-list-item>
                <custom-list-item id=2></custom-list-item>
                <custom-list-item id=3></custom-list-item>` 
        this.shadowRoot.addEventListener( 'click', this )
    }
    handleEvent( ev ) {
        console.log( ev.target.id )
    }
} )
```

```html
<custom-list></custom-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put an onclick event on `<custom-list onclick="doSomething()">` component and check for `event.target === custom-list-item` inside the function

```
doSomething(event) {
  event.target === custom-list-item
  // do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: For me, event.target is undefined.

Comment: can you tell how your event object looks like or the whole event object is undefined?

Comment: The whole object is undefined

Comment: can you try this `<custom-list onclick="doSomething(event)">` basically pass event as an argument and expect the same in function implementation

`function doSomething(event) {console.log(event)}`